# Need to get the First ordered date and last ordered date for all customers from order table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have order table which has information about all the customers orders. Now, I want to pull the first orderdate and last orderdate of the each and every customer.

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple `MIN` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT CustomerId, 
       MIN(OrderDate) Min_Order_Date
       MAX(OrderDate) Last_Order_Date
FROM dbo.Orders
GROUP BY CustomerId;
```